# Fit Content To Columns Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I'm working with XAML and I need to accomplish the following:

I have a series of buttons, and I need to be fit against a particular column when the resolution is changed.
Use the DockPanel element, but what achievement with that is that the column buttons suits. What I need is the opposite that the size of the buttons fit the column.
Any suggestions?

Here is the code

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Border Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" >
        <Grid Name ="grillaEditor">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="12*"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Border Grid.Row="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Button Width="30" Height="30" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"   >
                            <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="Resources/Images/Icons/undo-26.png" ></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Width="30" Height="30" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >
                            <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="Resources/Images/Icons/redo-26.png" ></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Width="30" Height="30" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Source="Resources/Images/Icons/paste-26.png" ></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Width="30" Height="30" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >
                            <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="Resources/Images/Icons/cut-26.png" ></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Width="30" Height="30" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Source="Resources/Images/Icons/copy-26.png" ></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Width="30" Height="30" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Source="Resources/Images/Icons/trash-26.png" ></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Width="30" Height="30"  >
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Source="Resources/Images/Icons/left_circular-26.png" ></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Width="30" Height="30"  >
                            <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="Resources/Images/Icons/right_circular-26.png" ></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Width="30" Height="30"" >
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Source="Resources/Images/Icons/up_circular-26.png" ></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Width="30" Height="30" >
                            <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="Resources/Images/Icons/down_circular-26.png" ></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Width="30" Height="30" >
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Source="Resources/Images/Icons/restart-26.png" ></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Width="30" Height="30" >
                            <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="Resources/Images/Icons/select_all-26.png" ></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Width="30" Height="30" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >
                            <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="Resources/Images/Icons/zoom_out-26.png" ></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Width="30" Height="30" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >
                            <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="Resources/Images/Icons/zoom_in-26.png" ></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Button Width="30" Height="30" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >
                            <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="Resources/Images/Icons/resize_four_directions-26.png" ></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
```

Comment: use a grid,maybe uniformgrid instead of the stackpanel and don't give the buttons a size

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the `Width` and the `Height` of the buttons, so they'll always try to be that size. Set a width and height on your column's StackPanel, then on the buttons set `HorizontalAlignment = Stretch` to have them fit the width of their parent container, or `VerticalAlignment = Stretch` to have them fit the height of it.

Comment: thank you very much but the size of the column is "50 *" means that varies depending on the resolution, how do I assign the StackPanel that size?